# Exception is not being captured

Tags: java, file, exception, load, custom-exceptions

I have a program where you can input name, surname, id and export them to a text file. The file can be imported back by using a load method. The problem with the load method is if you press the load button and don't select a file the list of errors will appear. I need to create an exception for these errors so the user will receive "Please Select a file" warning instead. So I created a custom exception:

```
    public class CancelException extends Exception {

    public CancelException() {
    }

    public CancelException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Then I tried to put it in the load method:

```
public static Person loadcons() throws IOException, CancelException {
    Person loadcons = null;
    try {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int chooserOption = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        chooserOption = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;

        File file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        loadcons = (Person) input.readObject();
        input.close();
        return loadcons;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new CancelException("Please select a file");
    }
    return null;

}

private String toString(String PersonID) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

The problem is that the exception is not being recognized and it is still giving me the exception stack trace instead of the warning.

The list of errors are below:

```
    Aug 17, 2015 12:41:50 PM ryan_assignment_sit2.CreateConsultant    jButton3ActionPerformed
   SEVERE: null
    ryan_assignment_sit2.CancelException: Please select a file
    at ryan_assignment_sit2.Person.loadcons(Person.java:105)
    at ryan_assignment_sit2.CreateConsultant.jButton3ActionPerformed(CreateConsultant.java:218)
    at ryan_assignment_sit2.CreateConsultant.access$300(CreateConsultant.java:29)
    at ryan_assignment_sit2.CreateConsultant$4.actionPerformed(CreateConsultant.java:87)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: and what does the exception say? Also why do you use the throws clause on the method and seperatly on the try catch block?

Comment: I put the list in the topic

Comment: I tried making them on the same method same issue.

Comment: What I see is you are getting `CancelException` at your stackTrace - so as the `throws` clause says your exception is being thrown. May be you don't catch it in a `loadcons()` caller method.

Comment: And just for info, if an exception is throw the variables in try clause aren't being initialized. So your `Person loadcons` variable sill will be `null` after an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check whether the file is selected or not by adding following condition:

```
if (chooser.getSelectedFile() == null)
{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a file", "No file selected", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

null ryan_assignment_sit2.CancelException: **Please select a file at ryan_assignment_**sit2.Person.loadcons(Person.java:105) at

Isn't it throwing an exception ? because you have passed the message to super class which is exception class.

you can try it just printing the warning using JOption pane instead?

Comment: so the message can't be shown using the exception ... sorry for lack of knowledge this is the first time doing this and I made this following a youtube video

Comment: just try it may be it help  :-)    http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingJOptionPanetoDisplayaMessage.htm